# How to not apply a function to a class? (I know nothing about html; this is probably an easy fix)

Tags: html, css, function, class, blogs

I'm very inexperience with html and only know the basics for my Tumblr blog. My question is probably very simple but I'm very pissed off at it and I'm losing sleep because I will not sleep without fixing it. So waaay in the beginning of my code, I have:

```
.post img { width: 100%; }
```

and then waaay later in the code, I have:

```
div class="asker-info"><img src="{AskerPortraitURL-24}" alt="" class="asker-avatar" /> {Asker}></div>
```

My problem here is that whenever someone asks me a question, their avatar appears 20x literally the size it should be. I've checked it out on Google Chrome's "inspect element" and found that the .post img part of my code cancels out with the width part in this section:

```
.asker-avatar {
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    }
```

I'm so goddamn pissed off and nothing makes sense

Comment: You want use 100% and not 24px?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this and tell what happens ?

Here you create a css class with the image size you want. You set the width what you want, and the height auto, it must pick a good value depending on height

```
.asker-avatar
{
 width: 24px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;

}
```

Another question, can you put here the *asker-info* class you use in the div ? Could be that class the problem with your img ? And maybe you could try to remove the .post img {width:100%} because can make the img to resize to the 100% width of the div

And here you can practise with images sizes and resizes, and you can read some explanation about the img attributes, it's an useful page:
[HTML_IMAGES W3SCHOOL](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that did nothing. I can't change anything in the .asker-avatar class if I don't change the .post img { width: 100% } (which I can't, otherwise the image posts will be messed up).

Comment: I want to know how to NOT apply .post img to .asker-avatar. I don't want to work around it, I want to completely avoid them working together.

Comment: Do you know how to manage the F12 editor ? If you do, Could you tell me the styles of the img loaded ? (Right-Click on the image, inspect element, and in the opened window, check in the right side for the css of the image)

Comment: .post img {
width: 100%;
}
.asker-avatar {
float: left;
width: 24px;
height: auto;
margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;

Comment: these are the ones I just posted so

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!! Oh my god, am I relieved! I noticed that my own avatar was not affected by the .post img so I looked over the  class and found out that by simply adding an id="*_*", you can change it!!

Comment: ...I'm not sure that makes any sense. Does it fix it in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the CSS selector `.post img` is "more specific" than the selector `.asker-avatar`.

Since `.asker-avatar` appears lower in the style-sheet that `.post img`, it will be enough to make that selector *as specific* as the one you want to override.

I'm not an expert on CSS specificity ([this guy](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) is), but try changing the `.asker-avatar` selector to `img.asker-avatar` (note - no space between `img` and `.`).